# upgrade OpenSSL from 0.9.8w to 1.0.0i or 1.0.1a on Linux server

Tags: linux, openssl

I want to upgrade OpenSSL from 0.9.8w to 1.0.0I or 1.0.1a.

I am using

```
os.name  Linux  
os.version  2.6.18-164.9.1.el5
```

Comment: Might help - [How do I upgrade OpenSSL](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6870/how-do-i-upgrade-openssl)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to pull the source using git and to build it yourself.

```
mkdir ~/openssl
cd ~/openssl
git clone git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git .
```

From the INSTALL document:

```
./config
make
make test
make install
```

The last command should be done as a superuser.

note that git checkout xxx can be used to pick the version you want to use.